# Exception with Python requests module, "requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout" is mutliple levels deep in code out of my control. How can I workaround?

Tags: python

There is no code to show as this is a conceptual question. So here is the concise concept breakdown:

Local server (my code) -calls-> acquire_remote_data function (my code) -calls-> data module (not my code) -data module uses-> requests (obviously not my code lol) which requests then throws the above titled exception if the server loses its internet connection temporarily.

I of course, first thing, used the "try/except" method in Python in the acquire_remote_data function to call the data module to quickly realize that it can't capture an exception so far down the path in modules I have no control over.

An option is to contact the author of the data module but who knows when, if ever, they will modify their code to capture the exception if they can.

Is there a workaround technique that can be used to keep this from crashing the server?

*** I figured it out. Using the try/except method was the correct first choice. However, I needed to use the except Exception catch all. I didn't really think of that the first time around because of my darn linter squawking about too general of an exception catch in the past. What I learned was how to shut my linter up about certain issues.

Comment: But how do you expect side library (data module) to handle failure of `requests`? Should it get some default value or maybe just retry? If so, why can't you implement it in your code?

Comment: I had the same thought of a retry but requests crashes with the exception and code execution stops. I would think the data module could implement the try/except technique and pass the exception along so I can implement the same in my code but until/if then I would need a workaround.